Calculation of Local Geary using ESDA & Pysal
I followed the example outlined in https://pysal.org/esda/generated/esda.Geary_Local.html
import libpysal as lp 
import geopandas as gpd
from esda import Geary_Local

guerry_ds = gpd.read_file(r"path_to_guerry\guerry.shp")

w_test = libpysal.weights.Queen.from_dataframe(guerry_ds) 
w_test.histogram
w_test.islands

y = guerry_ds["Donatns"] 
lG = Geary_Local(connectivity=w_test).fit(y) 

But I get
TypeError: to_adjlist() got an unexpected keyword argument 'drop_islands'.

I'm happy for any advice or guidance.
Many Thanks!
